# C# call method before and after button click

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have several buttons im my main window. I want the ones that open additional windows to disable main window before executing and enable after. Is there a different way to achieve that other than writing this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.IsEnabled = false;
            Some code...();
            this.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

in every method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a method to run your code through:

```
private void DisableAndExecute(Action action)
{
    this.IsEnabled = false;
    action();
    this.IsEnabled = true;
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DisableAndExecute(() =>
    {
        Some code...();
    });
}
```

This just means that your disabling and re-enabling is all done in one place.

You could also try using ShowModal instead of Show when opening your form:

```
form2.ShowModal();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding the event handlers manually you could do the following:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    btn.Click += Wrap(Button_Click);
}

public RoutedEventHandler Wrap(RoutedEventHandler handler)
{
    return (sender, e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            this.IsEnabled = true;
            handler(sender, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    };
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Code
}
```

Comment: You can add a parent child relationship to your windows, this way you won't have to disable your window and the child window will always be on top of the owner until it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parent child relationship to your windows, this way you won't have to disable your window and the child window will always be on top of the owner until it is closed. Like this:

```
SomeWindow childWindow = new SomeWindow();
childWindow.Owner = this;
childWindow.Show();
```